# paint an inherited control

Tags: c#

I have a class in my project, that inherits from Control and contains a few other items inside a groupbox:

```
class ProgressControl : Control
{
    private GroupBox TrackGroupBox;

    //some other stuff
}
```

I have overridden the Width, Top, Left etc top affect the groupbox and subitems. How Do I paint the groupbox when I do something like:

```
Panel.Controls.Add(ProgressControlInstance)
```

?

Comment: Where have you added the `GroupBox` to your controls control collection?

Comment: What do you mean by "paint"? Do you want to customize how the control is drawn using its `Paint` event handler? Or do you simply want to know how to make the control visible?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I just inherit from GroupBox :)